# Clickable link in a label for codename one?

Tags: codenameone

Using the designer only:
Is it possible to display a clickable link (to a web url) in a label or in another suitable component of Codename One? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a button, give it a different UIID and style it to look like a link.

Comment: Thanks! Just to know, why a different uuid?

Comment: And how do I attach an url to the button from the designer?

Comment: Different UIID to style it to look like a link, I'm assuming you don't want all the buttons to look like links. You can either use the action event then use `Display.execute` to launch the URL or assign a command to it and select the action as "execute" and give the URL.

Comment: it works fantastically well. Thanks for your quick answers and for developping this great designer!

Comment: @Seinecle could you please post the resulting code for this? I am not using the designer. Thank you.

Comment: Theming is separate from GUI. You can use the designer to customize a theme in a handcoded application too. See this quick tutorial covering the side menu but it explains working with the designer to style an app https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i-create-gorgeous-sidemenu.html