# HTML link for one word in Label text in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I have a label with some text and I want to have a few words in that text be a clickable HTML link. Is there any way to do this?

If not in a Label, is there a way to use the void paint(Graphics g) function to do this with raw drawing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flow layout e.g.:

```
Form hi = new Form("Richtext", BoxLayout.y());

Button clickable = new Button("link", "Label");
clickable.getAllStyles().setTextDecoration(Style.TEXT_DECORATION_UNDERLINE);

hi.add(FlowLayout.encloseMiddle(new Label("This"), new Label("is"), new Label("a"), clickable, new Label("to"), new Label("click")));
clickable.addActionListener(e -> ToastBar.showMessage("Click", FontImage.MATERIAL_INFO));

hi.show();
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks, this looks like it might work. My concern is that there is an unnatural amount of space between the labels. Is there any way to squeeze the labels together a bit more so that it appears like a line of text?

Comment: That's padding/margin. You can tune that

Comment: How exactly can I tune this? FlowLayout in codename one does not have gaps that can be set. Can you please point me to the methods I can use?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. You set the margin and padding to zero using style for the lements you are putting inside the FlowLayout. For the text on the left I used style=textField.getAllStyles() and then style.setMarginRight(0) and setPaddingRight(0). Also did this for left margin and padding on the button on the right.

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not certain, I don't think that can be done. However, I think this solution should do what you need:

See answer here: [Clickable link in a label for codename one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271550/clickable-link-in-a-label-for-codename-one)